# Network Connections error 720 windows 7

Tags: windows-7, networking, mobile-broadband

[image]

I use a Mobile Broadband connection to connect to the internet. Sometimes the connection disconnects and while I try to reconnect I get the error shown above.

After I logoff and logon again, then the connection works fine. Is there some way that I could flush the network settings in windows 7 so that I can avoid logging off and on all the time just to connect to internet.

I enabled logging and this is my [log](http://pastebin.com/mQZn1R05).

Answer (score -1):

Try this, open an [elevated command prompt](http://www.blogsdna.com/2168/windows-7-how-to-open-elevated-command-prompt-with-administrator-privileges.htm) and type in

> ipconfig /release all

hit enter key

now type in

> ipconfig /renew all

hit enter key.

does it work now?

Comment: `Windows IP Configuration

The operation failed as no adapter is in the state permissible for
this operation.`
Doesn't work.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your usb modem driver, update it if you can.

Comment: I get the same error with Bluetooth devices.

Comment: Disable your other network adapters in Device Manager when using mobile broadband, see if the problem persists.

Comment: How do you release the settings for an interface that isn't connected.

Comment: If it is not connected there is nothing to release, the reason I said to disable unused adapters in DM, unless i misunderstand you question.